# Sum specific range in R

Tags: r, sum

I want to sum A column using B column as criteria.

A                  B             C

1
2
3
4   TRUE    10

5
6
7   TRUE    18

8
9
10  TRUE    27

10 in C column is sum(1,2,3,4)
18 is sum(5,6,7)
27 is sum(10,9,8)

Answer (score 1):

A simple application of `ave` with groups defined by a variable computed by a `cumsum` trick will do what you want.

```
ave(df1$A, rev(cumsum(rev(df1$B))), FUN = cumsum)
#[1]  1  3  6 10  5 11 18  8 17 27
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
A B C
1 FALSE 1
2 FALSE 3
3 FALSE 6
4 TRUE 10
5 FALSE 5
6 FALSE 11
7 TRUE 18
8 FALSE 8
9 FALSE 17
10 TRUE 27                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice usage of `rev`

Answer (score 1):

Same function `ave` , but different idea to get the group function .

```
ave(df1$A,cumsum(c(F,diff(df1$B)==-1)),FUN=cumsum)
 [1]  1  3  6 10  5 11 18  8 17 27
```